# How do I find coverage for subprocesses under test?

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

Consider the following simple program:

```py
# thingy.py
import sys

print("ready")

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end='')
```

If I want to unit-test the program, I can stub out the side-effecting functions `ready` and `print` easily enough.

However, if I want to perform an end-to-end test, I want to run the real program and test real responses to real inputs.

I can test it easily enough:

```py
# test_thingy.py
import pytest
import subprocess
import sys    

@pytest.fixture
def thingy_instance(): 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [sys.executable, "-um", "thingy"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            encoding="utf-8")

    for line in proc.stdout:
        if "ready" in line:
            break
    yield proc
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()

def test_thingy(thingy_instance):
    stdout, stderr = thingy_instance.communicate("Hello!")
    assert stdout == "Hello!"

# more tests
```

However, if I try to generate coverage for this, it doesn't work:

```
$ coverage run --source . -m pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/user/playground-local/python/coverage-test-stuff
plugins: Faker-16.6.1, smtpdfix-0.4.0, quarantine-2.0.0, cov-3.0.0, mock-3.8.2, docker-tools-3.1.3, postgresql-4.1.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test_thingy.py .                                                         [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.09s ===============================
$ coverage report
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------
test_thingy.py      15      0   100%
thingy.py            4      4     0%
------------------------------------
TOTAL               19      4    79%
```

Running `coverage run -m thingy` generates coverage.

Running `coverage run --source . -m pytest` doesn't generate coverage.

Replacing the `Popen` command with a `coverage run -m` command doesn't generate coverage.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use the `-p` flag for `coverage run`, then run `coverage combine` after the fact.

From [the documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.3.1/cmd.html#execution-coverage-run):

```
  -p, --parallel-mode   Append the machine name, process id and random number
                        to the data file name to simplify collecting data from
                        many processes.
```

To get full coverage, replace the `Popen` python command with the coverage command, passing `-p`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def thingy_instance(): 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [sys.executable, "-um", "coverage", "run", "-pm", "thingy"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            encoding="utf-8")

    for line in proc.stdout:
        if "ready" in line:
            break
    yield proc
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()
```

*And* execute the top-level `coverage` command with `-p`:

```
$ coverage run --source . -pm pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/user/playground-local/python/coverage-test-stuff
plugins: Faker-16.6.1, smtpdfix-0.4.0, quarantine-2.0.0, cov-3.0.0, mock-3.8.2, docker-tools-3.1.3, postgresql-4.1.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test_thingy.py .                                                         [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.16s ===============================
```

Then run `coverage combine`:

```
$ coverage combine
Combined data file .coverage.my-host.1383878.098470
Combined data file .coverage.my-host.1383874.892749
```

Finally, the `coverage report` (as well as coverage generation commands) will include all sub-process runs:

```
$ coverage report
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------
test_thingy.py      15      0   100%
thingy.py            4      0   100%
------------------------------------
TOTAL               19      0   100%
```